# "use of undeclared identifier '_blsr_u64'" with Intel C++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

As the title says, I'm getting this compilation error when using the intel c++ (2024) compiler.

I'm using Visual Studio to code and compile. It works fine with the VS compiler.

These are the two relevant lines in my code:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

#define Bitloop(X) for(;X; X = _blsr_u64(X))
```

Does anyone have experience with the intel compiler and why it doesn't work? Should I include another library?

Comment: How do you invoke the compiler?

Comment: @273K using Visual Studio simply running the program (the intel compiler is integrated with VS)

Comment: I meant the compliler options.

Comment: @273K I'm not sure how to see that. This is the "command line": /GS /GA /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /O3 /Ob2 /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER=20240000" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Qipo /Zc:forScope /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /fprofile-ml-use /Fo"x64\Release\" /Ot /Fp"x64\Release\chessbit.pch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the include folders of each compiler, I noticed that `_blsr_u64` was not defined in the intel one (as well as clang).
It is defined in another library (`bmiintrin.h`) which cannot be directly included.

It is in theory `x86intrin.h` that should be included but I'm also getting an error: `cannot open source file "x86intrin.h"` even though it exists.

Anyway I gave up and used the implementation I found within `bmiintrin.h`

```
__blsr_u64(unsigned long long __X)
{
  return __X & (__X - 1);
}
```

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it to change the thread's status to Answered.  Just a reminder :)